# How to get Menu Item title in different Locale on selection?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm implementing an app which uses both English and Arabic Locale, I already implemented how the language gets changed and all that.

My problem is now I have a Menu that contains items with `title:@String/some_string_name`, when the user chooses an option, in English I always just took the title using `MenuItem.getTitle` which is in English and send it as a node name in an HTTP request.
Now when I change to Arabic, when I use `MenuItem.getTitle` I get the title which is shown currently to the user in Arabic, I can't use that for the server node name !!

I can't find a valid solution that solves my problem, how should I get an English representation of the string shown currently in the MenuItem (without hardcoding anything) ?